# How to pivot table and display data in table format using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table

I don't know much about programming so if my question and description are two different things then sorry but please help me to solve my problem .

For better understanding i am providing my fiddle where you will get idea about what i actually want but then too read my whole question first.
and image too.

So, basically i have some kind of tables and then with the help of sql joins i join them:

```
SELECT fintran.ledgerId, 
       chartofaccounts.mainGroupId, 
       chartofaccounts.categoryGroup, 
       chartofaccounts.detailGroup, 
       chartofaccounts.subGroup,
       fintran.netValue 
FROM   fintran 
INNER JOIN chartofaccounts 
ON     chartofaccounts.chartId = fintran.ledgerId 
INNER JOIN maingroup 
ON     chartofaccounts.chartId = maingroup.mainGroupId 
WHERE  fintran.societyId = 2
```

[image: this is my output what i get after inner join my tables]

this is my fiddle i write some static code if you compare my image output and my fiddle's table data you will come to know that what i want from my query. as you can see in `detailgroup`=> `other funds` comes multiple times. i want to display it only once with `SUM` of all values. please refer my **output image** and **fiddle** for the same.

```css
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

```html
<table id="datatable-buttons"  class="table  table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headings">                              
      <th class="column-title">Liabilties</th>
      <th class="column-title">netvalue</th>                
    </tr>                                                
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="even pointer">                                 
    <td class="number11"><b>Share capital</b></td>
      <td class=" "></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even pointer">                                 
      <td class="number11">&nbsp;&nbsp;issued subcribed</td>
      <td class=" ">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even pointer">                                 
      <td class="number11"><b>Reserve and other funds</b></td>
      <td class=" ">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even pointer">                                 
      <td class="number11">&nbsp;&nbsp;Sinking Fund</td>
      <td class=" ">9</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="even pointer">                                 
      <td class="number11">&nbsp;&nbsp;building fund</td>
      <td class=" ">9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even pointer">                                 
      <td class="number11">&nbsp;&nbsp;other fund</td>
      <td class=" ">850</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Looks like you just need `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`. There's no pivoting required.

Comment: can you provide me with code @Barmar sir?

Comment: ok sir i will try something